# AppEngine (Python): can I know programmatically how much memory is used by the current instance?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

In the AppEngine control panel I can see the active instances and how much memory they are using.

Is it possible to get the same information programmatically?

I mean, when a request is processed, is there a function I can call that will return the number of bytes currently used by the instance that is handling the request?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from google.appengine.api import runtime

runtime.memory_usage().current()
```

[docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/runtimeapi)